# Is there a way to return the same errorCode for a group of fluentValidation validations?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I have a .net 7 api project where we are using fluentValidation to validate our models. I would like to know if there is an elegant way of returning the same error code for a group of validation rules. I want this so that i can let the user know what category of error does the current validation failure belong to.

For example say I have a ProductValidator

```
public ProductValidator()
{
    RuleFor(model => model.Name).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(100);
    RuleFor(model => model.Description).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(1000);
    RuleFor(model => model.ProductType).IsInEnum();
}
```

I want all validations in this "block" to return the error code "ERR0001" without having to use .WithErrorCode() on each and every extension. In other words, I dont want to do this:

```
public ProductValidator()
{
    RuleFor(model => model.Name).NotEmpty().WithErrorCode("ERR0001").MaximumLength(100).WithErrorCode("ERR0001");
    RuleFor(model => model.Description).NotEmpty().WithErrorCode("ERR0001").MaximumLength(1000).WithErrorCode("ERR0001");
    RuleFor(model => model.ProductType).IsInEnum().WithErrorCode("ERR0001");
}
```

Ultimately, i want the user of the api to be able to refer to an error code documentation where they can look up what category of validation error this is (e.g.: ERR0001: Simple model validation failure etc.).

Comment: Do you wanna achieve each `AbstractValidator<T>` has it's unique error code message?